# Why does passing by reference involve a copy constructor?

Tags: c++

In Deitel C++ book ("C++11 for Programmers", p.286) , there is an example of:

```
class Date { ... }

class Employee {
public:
   Employee(const string &, const string &, const Date &, const Date &);
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    const Date birthDate;
    const Date hireDate;
}

Employee::Employee( const string &first, const string &last, 
   const Date &dateOfBirth, const Data &dateOfHire)
   : firstName( first),
     lastName( last),
     birthDate(dateOfBirth),
     hireDate(dateOfHire) { };
```

The book says the member initializer such as `birthDate(dateOfBirth)` invoked `Date` class's copy constructor. I am confused as to why copy constructor? I thought the whole point of "pass by reference" is to avoid the object copy?

If I do:

```
Date birth(7,24, 1959);
Date hire(2,12, 1988);
Employer staff("bob", "blue", birth, hire);
```

How many Date objects does the system have now, 2 or 4? (Two created at the start, two are created by copy constructor)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is not the passing mode that involves a copy.

It is the initialization of the members that involve a copy (obviously? the parameters don't live in the class, and the class members need to get the same value: copy)

Let's examine

```
Employee::Employee(const string& first, const string& last,
                   const Date& dateOfBirth, const Data& dateOfHire)
    : firstName(first)
    , lastName(last)
    , birthDate(dateOfBirth)
    , hireDate(dateOfHire) { }

int main() {
    const std::string fname = "test";
    Employee e(fname, /* ..... */);
}
```

1. We invoke `Employee::Employee`, passing `fname` by `const&` (*no copy*).
2. The constructor initializes it's member firstname from the first parameter
3. This exercises `std::string(const std::string&)`, again passing the parameter on by `const&` (still no copy).
4. The `std::string` copy constructor now takes all necessary steps to copy the the value of it's parameter into the object itself. **This is the copy**

It makes sense that when you construct a new `std::string` (in this case as a member of Employee), it results in a ... new `std::string`. Thinking of it this way makes it very easy to grasp, I think.

Comment: so, there are indeed 2 new Date object created by the act of copy constructor, just as new object of std:string are created, am I understanding you correct? thx

Comment: In this case, the object instances appear as members of the Employee class, and they are merely _initialized_ (by their copy constructors) in place. But logically, yes, all these members are initialized to become copies of their respective initializers **and** they have just begun life, allocated as part of the Employee object. **An Employee has-a string,string,Date,Date**, so to say

Answer (score 5):

The point of "pass by reference" is to not make a copy as soon as Employee constructor is called, but only when you choose to initialize one of Employee's member with the Date passed.

Comment: Succinctly worded, +1. Nitpick: no assignment is involved, since the members are _initialized_ from the initializer list.

Comment: C++, always the best to put your foot in your mouth.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant, but rest assured I said it in good spirit :) I personally feel (too?) that adhering to the correct terminology is boring and _meh_ sometimes, but it is the only way to build a deeper understanding (how else are you going to _know_ when a copy constructor is invoked, or rather the assignment operator? This is relevant stuff, and could be a show stopper if your class contained reference members.) Anyway, I'm getting off-topic. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Your original object `birth` is indeed passed by reference to the `Employee` copy constructor, so no copy is made at that stage. However, when the `Employee` copy is being constructred, the **member** `Employee::birthDate` object is initialized by using *its own* copy constructor, to which the outer `birth` object is passed by reference, but that copy constructor will of course make a copy of the `birth` object, which becomes the `Employee::birthDate` member object.

Answer (score 4):

These two lines are going to invoke the Date's copy constructor :

```
 birthDate(dateOfBirth),
 hireDate(dateOfHire)
```